# How to create a recast navigation mesh in code without game pipeline tools

Tags: navigation, mesh

I have a PostGIS database that I store building 2D footprint polygons and building height. I have DAL that returns polygons and heights in latitude,longitude perimeters and I can convert these to polygons with X,Y coordinates in linear space. I am interested adding path finding support for walking between and around buildings from an origin and destination in my grid.
Navigation meshes seem to the most applicable technology (especially since I would eventually like to add 3D support after I implement 2D path finding). Recast seems to be the most promising open source technology for using Nav meshes but most of the articles and technical sample discussing Recast are related to the gaming world and assume tools and pipelines that I do not have in my system.

Does anyone have any advice or samples for using Recast starting with simple extruded polygons on an X,Y grid to create navigation mesh for path finding?